# TypeDescriptor Not Found in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, prism

I found this Validation Example for MVVM WPF at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Validation-in-MVVM-using-12dafef3

I'm trying to use it In my Silverlight 5 project. The challenge is Silverlight 5 doesn't have 
TypeDescriptor in its ComponentModel dll.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/02/19/automapper-for-silverlight-3-0-alpha/

So How I can Use it or is there Any work Around for this. I don't know much about reflections.

Please guide.

```
 var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType()).Find(propertyName, false);
            if (propertyDescriptor == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(this);
            _values.Add(propertyName, value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not xxx.GetType().GetProperties() ?

Comment: I forgot to Post Ans. I used in the same way. Thanks